# Flex mobile: cross navigation from one view navigator to other

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex-mobile

Suppose I have two tabs in my app:

```
<ViewNavigator id="tab1" firstView="Tab1">
<ViewNavigator id="tab2" firstView="Tab2">
```

I go into Tab1, and start pushing other views onto the stack

```
navigator.pushView(Tab1View1)
navigator.pushView(Tab1View2)
```

and so on....

Now I want to jump directly, with NO TRANSITIONS, from one of the views deep in Tab1, into one of the views in Tab2. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you [pushView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ViewNavigator.html#pushView%28%29),  or pop, you can specify the transition.  I would have expected that setting it to null will give you no transition.

Answer (score 0):

> When you pushView, or pop, you can specify the transition. I would
>   have expected that setting it to null will give you no transition.

No. If you pass null as transition parameter, navigator uses defaultPopTransition and defaultPushTransition.
You need use

```
private function onCreationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
  navigator.transitionsEnabled=false;
}
```